# What is Perl's $; variable for?

Tags: perl, scalar

Does any 1 have any idea what is `$;` (first split function argument) in the following code snippet:

```
      local(@a) = ();
      local($i) = 0;
      for ($i = 0; $i < $d; $i++) {
         @a = split($;, @b[$i]);
         $c     = @a[0];
      }
```

The scalar is not found any where in the script other than in the for loop.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wow, that must be some old code.

Comment: Must be *really* old code -- `$;` was deprecated with the first release of Perl 5, IIRC. There's certainly no use for it after Perl 4.

Comment: no, it's not deprecated; perl4-style multi-dimenional arrays are still handy where you have very large, sparse datastructures and you only care about the leaves.

Comment: '$;' with 'local', non-list 'for' and '@a[0]' not '$a[0]' means old Perl 4 code.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578671/where-can-i-find-information-about-perls-special-variables

Answer (score 13):

Perl's special variables are documented in `perlvar`, including [`$;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%3b)

> #### $SUBSEP
>
> #### **$;**
>
> The subscript separator for multidimensional array emulation. If you refer to a hash element as
>
> ```
> $foo{$a,$b,$c}
> ```
>
> it really means
>
> ```
> $foo{join($;, $a, $b, $c)}
> ```
>
> But don't put
>
> ```
> @foo{$a,$b,$c}  # a slice--note the @
> ```
>
> which means
>
> ```
> ($foo{$a},$foo{$b},$foo{$c})
> ```
>
> Default is `"\034"`, the same as `SUBSEP` in awk. If your keys contain binary data there might not be any safe value for `$;`. (Mnemonic: comma (the syntactic subscript separator) is a semi-semicolon. Yeah, I know, it's pretty lame, but `$,` is already taken for something more important.)
>
> Consider using "real" multidimensional arrays as described in [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html).

We could guess about why it's being used (*e.g.*, maybe `@b` contains some hash's keys), but knowing how `@b` is created would let us provide more helpful answers.

Note also that `@b[$i]` and `@a[0]` should probably be

```
$b[$i]
```

and

```
$a[0]
```

instead. With the leading `@`, they're single-element array slices, but with `$`, they're simple scalars.

Answer (score 0):

The Perl special variables are listed in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: Why did you link to some random (and outdated) page when you could have linked to the official Perl documentation?

Comment: NB: brian d foy has edited the question and it now links to the official documentation.